# Add a div to a cell

Tags: mxgraph

which is the cleanest way to have a  on top of a cell? I need to have this div with a speciifc id covering the whole extension of the cell. Now i have given an HTML value to the cell: this value is a div containing a table set up to cover the default size of the cell. But obviously, on resize, it doesn't work.

The setVAlue code:
    cell.setValue('< table id="'+cell.getId()+'" style="">< tbody>< tr>< td style="min-width: 80px; text-align: center;">< br>< br>< br>< /td>< /tr>< /tb>

Answer (score 1):

Try `overflow=fill` in the cell style and use `graph.setHtmlLabels(true)`.